# How to obfuscate or minify Javascript files

Tags: javascript, netbeans, build-script

I'm doing a web based java application using Netbeans IDE, There are some javascript files in netbeans IDE.  I need to Obfuscate or minify my javascript files automatically when I clean and build the project, Is there any solution for that? or do I need to write any build script , please provide me a solution

Comment: *"Obfuscate or minify"* - Which?

Comment: use an obfuscater to obfuscate, use a minifier to minify - hth

Answer (score 1):

You can use gulp. Gulp has a great gulp-uglify plugin for that(https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple website and you don't want to use advanced solutions like task runner (Gulp) you can simply use website like this one - https://jscompress.com/ - and minify your all files after your page is done.

Comment: "_I need to Obfuscate or minify my javascript files automatically ..._" Looks like OP wants to use some advanced solutions?